# What's the shortest distance from a point inside of an ellipsoid to its surface?

Tags: optimization, computational-geometry, non-convex-optimization, qcqp

In general in arbitrary dimension, what's the shortest distance from a point inside of an ellipsoid to its surface?

Any good resources on this topic would help greatly as well.

Edit: I know there are ways to do this with constrained optimization, but what I'm wondering is if there's a way to do this analytically.

Comment: A requirement for a point to be closest to a point on a differentiable manifold is that the vector between the points is orthogonal to the local tangent space of the differentiable manifold ( in other words it should be along one of the normals to the point on the surface which it is closest ).

Comment: Could you provide a reference for that?

Comment: I can see if I can do that maybe tomorrow. I am kind of mobile right now so I don't have my books around.

Comment: Just cut the ellipsoid by any plane that passes through the given point and a chosen (fixed) point on the ellipsoid. The curve in the intersection should be perpendicular to the line through the points or else you can get closer.

Comment: Consider a small sphere centred at your point, and expand it until it first touches the ellipsoid.  Where it does touch, the normals to the ellipsoid and the sphere will coincide; the (inward) normal to the sphere is in the direction of your point.

Answer (score 9):

If the point is $p$ and the ellipsoid is $x^T Q x = 1$, you want to minimize
$(x-p)^T(x-p)$ subject to $x^T Q x = 1$, where $Q$ is a (symmetric) positive definite matrix.  Using a Lagrange multiplier, we take
$$ F = (p-x)^T(p-x) + \lambda (x^T Q x -1)$$  Then we want
$$\nabla F = 2 (x-p) + 2 \lambda Q x = 0
$$
i.e. $x = (I+\lambda Q)^{-1} p$
where $\lambda$ is chosen so
$x^T Q x = p^T (I+\lambda Q)^{-2} Q p = 1$.

EDIT: There should be at least two real solutions of this equation, of which some will make $x = (I+\lambda Q)^{-1} p$ a local minimum of the distance and others make it a local maximum.

Comment: Let $\mu$ denote the Lagrange multiplier. What if $\mu = -\frac{1}{\lambda_k (Q)}$?

Comment: Good point.  In that case, we need $p$ to be in the range of $I + \mu Q$.  Then there will be an affine subspace of $x$ with $(I+\mu Q) x = p$; if there is such an $x$ with $x^T Q x \le 1$, there will be some with $x^T Q x = 1$.