# Distance between a point and an Ellipsoid

Tags: calculus, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

Find the distance from the point $P = (9, 4, 5)$ to the ellipsoid $x^2 + 2y^2 + 4z^2 = 16$. Then, find the distance if the ellipsoid is restricted to first octant.

I tried using the distance formula according to optimization: $$d = \frac{|ax_0 + by_0 + cz_0|}{\|n\|}$$

I plugged in the  coefficients (n) of the ellipsoid (1,2,4) into the formula as a,b,and c respectfully. Then, I plugged the points $9,4,5$ as $x_0$, $y_0$ and $z_0$. I also calculated the norm of $n$, $$d = \frac{|1(9) + 2(4) + 4(5)|}{\|\sqrt{21}\|}$$

I didn't really understand the other part of the first octant.

It gives me an answer but I am not sure if is the right approach. Thanks.

Comment: Interesting problem but you didn't include any attempt. Sadly this means it will likely get closed and then no one can answer it.

Comment: How do you define the distance between a point and a surface? As noticed, you should show in detail what you have tried.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I've voted to reopen because it seems that OP has improved the original question. Do you agree with that? Thanks

Comment: @RobertIsrael I've noticed now you closed the question as a duplicate. Anyway it seems the two question are in some way different since the previous one is more general while this one is about a concrete case. Maybe also the given answers are sufficiently different. In any case if you think ismust be closed,please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The normal vector to the ellipsoid at the point on the surface $Q=(x,y,z)$ is

$$n_Q=(2x,4y,8z)$$

and the condition for the distance from $P = (9, 4, 5)$ is that $PQ\parallel n_Q$ that is

$$(2x,4y,8z)=t (x-9, y-4, z-5)$$

that is $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac{9t}{t-2},\frac{4t}{t-4},\frac{5t}{t-8}\right) $ which leads [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%289t%2F%28t-2%29%29%5E2%2B2%284t%2F%28t-4%29%29%5E2%2B4%285t%2F%28t-8%29%29%5E2%3D16) to the following solutions

- $t\approx -1.27283 \implies Q_1\approx\left(3.500169,0.965575,0.686361\right) \implies d_1\approx 7.619954$
- $t\approx 0.593020 \implies Q_2\approx\left(-3.793350,-0.696240,-0.400311\right)\implies d_2\approx 14.659053$

---

As an alternative by Lagrange multipliers we need to minimize

$$d(x,y,z)=(x-9)^2+(y-4)^2+(z-5)^2$$

with the condition $x^2+2y^2+4z^2-16=0$ which lead to

- $x-9=\lambda x$
- $y-4=2\lambda y$
- $z-5=4\lambda z$

which lead to $(x,y,z)=\left(\frac 9{1-\lambda},\frac 2{1-2\lambda},\frac 5{1-4\lambda}\right)$ and [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%289%2F%281-t%29%29%5E2%2B2%284%2F%281-2t%29%29%5E2%2B4%285%2F%281-4t%29%29%5E2%3D16) to the following solutions

- $\lambda \approx -1.571305 \implies Q_1\approx\left(3.500169,0.965575,0.686361\right) \implies d_1\approx 7.619954$
- $\lambda\approx 3.372573 \implies Q_2\approx\left(-3.793350,-0.696240,-0.400311\right)\implies d_2\approx 14.659053$

---

In both case we conclude that the distance is $d=d_1=|PQ_1|\approx 7.619954$ with $Q_1$ in the first octanct which seems an obvious result since $P$ itself is located in the first octant.

As you noticed, this part of the problem looks not very well stated.

---

Graphical sketch

[image]

---

Refer also to the related

- [Normal of a point on the surface of an ellipsoid](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2931909/505767)
- [What's the shortest distance from a point inside of an ellipsoid to its surface?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2374136/505767)

Comment: Let me know if it works, I've not checked all the details! You are welcome! Bye

Comment: The thing about restricting the ellipsoid to first octant or not seems uninteresting since the point $P$ is also in the first octant?

Comment: Maybe it is considered relevant since it is just the (minimum) distance.

Comment: But the answer should be the same? Maybe it would be more interesting to restrict the surface to the _opposite_ octant, or just one of the octants not containing $P$?

Comment: We should obtain two different “distances” with that for the first octant smaller. I’ll check this better with a sketch for the situation.

Comment: $PQ \parallel n_Q $ gives the equation $(2x, 4y, 8z) \times (x - 9, y - 4, z - 5) = 0 $ and not what you've written.

Comment: @MoneyManagementSkills I was indeed looking at that! Thanks a lot, I fix all.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen I've revised completely the answer for my previuos mistake. Unfortunately I can obtain just numerical solutions, without a closed form.

Comment: @MoneyManagementSkills I've revised completely the answer for my previuos mistake. Unfortunately I can obtain just numerical solutions, without a closed form.

Comment: I still do not think it clarifies the thing about the first octant (by which is usually meant the set $\{ (x,y,z) \mid x>0 \text{ and }y>0\text{ and }z>0 \}$), and it may be a flaw in the problem quoted by the asker? In your new image, $Q_1$ seems to be the point nearest to $P$, and $Q_2$ is the point _farthest_ from $P$. So $Q_2$ does not seem to be the relevant point for the second sentence of the problem.

Comment: Yes, I see your point and I agree with you. The problem is not well stated in this form. I add also a comment on that. Thanks